How do I render ipyleaflet MAP to my dash web app
I am attempting to integrate a leaflet map into my Dash application, but I'm having trouble rendering it as HTML. Could someone assist with the following code snippet?
def update_map(n_clicks, input_value1, input_value2, marker_info=None):
if n_clicks > 0:
    if input_value1 is None or input_value2 is None:
        raise PreventUpdate

    # Check if input values are not empty strings
    if not input_value1.strip() or not input_value2.strip():
        raise PreventUpdate

    directions_json = get_directions(input_value1, input_value2)
      
    route_line=convert_to_polyline(directions_json)
    
    
    towers_near_highway= Geo_towers[Geo_towers.intersects(route_line)]
    
   
    towers_near_highway = towers_near_highway[towers_near_highway['SITENAME'].str.len() == 6]
    
    # Create a Folium map centered at a default location
    mymap = Map(center=(36.8, 3), zoom=10, scroll_wheel_zoom=True)
    
    polyline= Polyline(locations=route_line.coords[:], color="blue", fill_opacity=0)
    mymap.add_layer(polyline)
    
   # Convert the map to HTML
    map_html = mymap._repr_html_()

    # Return the HTML iframe element
    return html.Iframe(srcDoc=map_html, style={"height": "500px", "width": "100%"})
else:
    raise PreventUpdate

